# Can the Processor in the Apple Watch Ultra Beat an Old Pentium 4 CPU in Terms of Raw Performance?

Tags: performance, apple-watch, cpu, intel

I was staring at my watch and remembered an old Pentium 4 PC I had as a kid. This got me thinking, does my watch have more compute power than that PC did? I'm leaning towards a hard yes, but it's difficult to get a hold of benchmarks for the Apple Watch (probably due to tooling availability, and the fact that most people don't care). I know the later Pentium CPUs were clocked in the 3+ GHz range which is probably higher than what the Apple Watch runs at, but a higher clock speed is not a good indication of better performance since you can execute more instructions within a given clock cycle anyways in addition to the performance gains of a modern instruction set.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in terms of raw performance, a new Apple Watch beats an old Pentium 4.

The Pentium 4 actually spans a number of models released over a timespan of almost 6 years. The most recent Pentium 4 in its most expensive edition was approx. 4.5 times faster than the original model.

If you look at it in terms of transistor count, you can see the huge difference:

- Pentium 4 anno 2000: 42 million transistors
- Pentium 4 anno 2006: 188 million transistors

The CPU frequency of the original Pentium 4 was 1.4 Ghz, but later models were released with up to 3.8 Ghz.

However, comparing that to the most recent Apple Watch processors, makes it obvious that we have come a long way since then:

- Apple S8 in Apple Watch Ultra: 3.5 billion transistors
- Apple S9 in Apple Watch Ultra 2: 5.6 billion transistors

The CPU frequency of the S8 is 1.8 Ghz in comparison.

Note that the Pentium 4 was a single-core design, where the S8/S9 are dual-core CPUs. The S8/S9 obviously feature a much different power consumption compared to Pentium 4s.

Also note that you cannot compare CPUs on transistor count alone. You cannot take a single metric to benchmark (such as floating point operations or whatever) and just compare the transitor counts to say that one CPU is x times faster than the other.

Modern CPUs such as the S9 dedicate a lot of transistors for specialised compute functionality, such as for example machine learning processing. At the time of the original Pentium 4, such specialized functionality was for example the MMX and SSE instruction sets (which the S9 contains modern equivalents to).